# Process fails on formula field - Is it order of execution issue?

Tags: formula-field, process-builder, order-of-execution

I have a formula field, that is based on Account billing country.

The field (called: Account Region) Defines a set of regions per country, or set's the default to: ROW (Never Null or empty)

My Formula field looks like this

```
IF(LEN( BillingCountry)=0, "ROW", 
IF(CONTAINS("ישראל:israel", LOWER(BillingCountry) ), "Israel", 
IF(CONTAINS("india:sri lanka:form_india", LOWER(BillingCountry) ), "India", 
IF(CONTAINS("united states:canada:form_us", LOWER(BillingCountry) ), "North America", 
IF(CONTAINS("congo, republic of the", LOWER(BillingCountry) ), "Africa", 
IF(CONTAINS("anguilla:antigua and barbuda", LOWER(BillingCountry) ), "LATAM", 
IF(CONTAINS("aland islands:albania:algeria:andorra:form_europe", LOWER(BillingCountry) ), "Europe", 
IF(CONTAINS("yemen:form_apac", LOWER(BillingCountry) ), "APAC", "ROW"))))))))
```

My process takes leads/contacts added to campaign, and updates a custom field on campaign_member with the Lead Region/Contact.Account.Accont_region fields - respectively)

The error I get is:

> An error occurred at element myRule_1_A1 (FlowRecordUpdate). The flow
>   failed to access the value for
>   myVariable_current.Contact.Account.Account_Region__c because it hasn't
>   been set or assigned.

My question: If my field always gets a value, how come it's :Null or Not assigned?

Also, I checked for permissions on the profile that does the changes, and the custom fields.

Both custom fields - are read only for all profiles.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that when doing cross object stuff with Process Builder it is hit or miss on if it finds a value or not. There are some bugs there.

What I have done it create a formula field on the initiating object that basically references the desired field (in your case Contact.Account.Account_Region__c) and then it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there are contacts with out accounts. Thus, going for the account->account.region returns an error (I wish it would alert that the entire object 'account' is missing, and not just the field.)

Solution: update the process builder to check if contact.account_id exists.